# LotusScript Type mismatch on external name

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

Lotus Notes 8.5.3, I am running into an issue where I cannot get the form to load the script library.  I get "Type mismatch on external name: RECEIPT" (where "Receipt" is one of the types in my script library).

I have tried:
- editing and resaving the form
- editing and resaving the library
- Project > Clean, rebuilding everything
- Shutting down and restarting Notes
- Shutting down and restarting my computer

Nothing has helped.

Notes Help says that this means that a type has changed since the client of that type was compiled.  I would have expected that rebuilding everything (including the form that has its Use statement) would solve it, but it doesn't.

Any suggestions?

Comment: IMO this error happens when you try to use the class, not upon loading. You could try to "touch" the place where your code is used like button or form script. I have an impression that "recompile all lotusscript" sometimes does not really act on all pieces of code (or maybe something is being cached)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ultimate solution: When you have a type mismatch on an external name, comment the Use statement for the library in question from the form, then try to save it.  It will fail with the first use of a class defined in the library, and prevent you from saving the form.  But it will also clear the cached definitions, which will allow you to uncomment the Use statement and successfully save the form.

Answer (score 4):

You could try:

- Open the database in the Designer client and select "Recompile all LotusScript" from the Tools menu.
- Copy the code out of the script library, delete it, then create a new script library and paste the code back in.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to copy the script that uses RECEIPT into directly the library and get a clearer error message. You can try it in a copy database (not the original).

I remember in old versions of Lotus the form got crazy on libraries. But I doubt it is this case.

I suspect you are using an array of a type different that Variant and handling it to a function or sub as variant (or vice verse).

In lotus script there is CVar to convert to Variant,

In case array of objects, you might need to cast the object retrieved from an array to an Object then hand it to the function (if it has an object as parameter).